# Target element with 2 classes inside a jquery not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I can't seem to get this to work, it is probably pretty simple but here we go:

This is my selector and I want to look for an element with both the selection[0] and selection[1] class but this does not look for an element that has both. As far as I can tell it only grabs the first selection class and looks for that.

```
$(this).not("." + selection[0], "." + selection[1]).hide();
```

I've tried manually inputting it like this and it works:

```
$(this).not(".class1.class2").hide();
```

I'm guessing the comma seperates the selectors and it is going wrong there. How can I achieve the same functionality though?

Comment: `$(this).not("." + selection[0] + "." + selection[1]).hide();` - use `+` to concatenate those 2 strings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace comma `,` with `+` to concatenate *selection[0]* with dot `.`

```
$(this).not("." + selection[0] + "." + selection[1]).hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Pretty hard to find an answer like that by looking with google since it is not that easy to formulate. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
$(this).not("." + selection[0], "." + selection[1]).hide();
```

has a syntax error (not from JS point of view but jquery selector point of view)

make it

```
$(this).not("." + selection[0] + "." + selection[1]).hide(); //replaced comma with +
```

Comment: It is not actually a syntax error (this use of the comma operator is valid JavaScript), but it results in an invalid selector.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `only` was a typo :)